# Does the ATO recognise a PayPal business account as a valid business account?

Tags: tax-law, australia

The Australian Tax Office requires that all registered companies have a dedicated bank account for their business.

Does the ATO recognise a PayPal business account as a valid business account?

I've tried my best to find a definitely answer on the ATO site, however it is not explicitly mentioned.